# Is quantum interference only observed for observables that have a continuous spectrum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space, interference, superposition

The probability distribution for an observable with a **discrete** spectrum is defined by an inner product operation (and implemented as a dot product) on its wave function. $$\langle \psi|\psi\rangle$$ If $\psi$ is expressed as a superposition of eigenvectors $\left\{|\psi_1\rangle,|\psi_2\rangle \right \}\ $  $$|\psi\rangle=\alpha|\psi_1\rangle + \beta|\psi_2\rangle$$ then the corresponding probability distribution is given by \begin{equation}\langle\psi|\psi\rangle=\alpha^2|\psi_1|^2+\beta^2|\psi_2|^2\end{equation}  With the restriction that $\alpha^2+\beta^2 = 1$. $$$$The probability distribution for an observable with a **continuous** spectrum is also formed by an inner product but in this case the inner product is defined as an integral of the product of the wave functions $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^*(x)\psi(x)dx$$ If $\psi(x) $is a superposition of two states, such as $$\psi(x) = \alpha\psi_1(x)+\beta\psi_2(x)$$then $$\psi^*(x)\psi(x)=\alpha^2|\psi_1(x)|^2 + \beta^2|\psi_2(x)|^2 + 2\alpha\beta\psi_1(x)\psi_2(x)$$ I should probably integrate this $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\alpha^2|\psi_1(x)|^2 + \beta^2|\psi_2(x)|^2 + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}2\alpha\beta\psi_1(x)\psi_2(x)$$There is a interference term (the second integral) present for the continuous spectrum case that is not present for the discrete spectrum case. Is this true? Is quantum interference only observed for observables that have a continuous spectrum? Does the interference term integrate to zero if $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are orthogonal? And if so, what does that mean with respect to interference?

NOTE: Based on the comments I can rephrase my question to the following. Is the following equation true? $$\langle\psi|\psi\rangle = |\psi|^2$$ I think this where I have a misunderstanding. I suspect it is not true but I do not immediately see why.

Comment: If $\psi(x) $is a superposition of two states, such as $\psi(x) = \alpha\psi_1(x)+\beta\psi_2(x)$ then $\psi^*(x)\psi(x)=\alpha^2|\psi_1(x)|^2 + \beta^2|\psi_2(x)|^2 + 2\alpha\beta\psi_1(x)\psi)2(x)$ the interference term is always there irrespective of the spectrum is discrete or continuous.

Comment: Are you sure about that? For a discrete spectrum we do not multiply the two wave functions, we take the dot product, which is different.

Comment: Yes, I am sure besides the typo in the equation (irrelevant for this question) I just copied form yours, it should really read $\psi^*(x)\psi(x)=|\alpha|^2||\psi_1(x)|^2 + |\beta^2||\psi_2(x)|^2 + 2\Re{(\alpha^* \beta \psi_1(x)^*\psi_2(x))}$

Comment: Well, if you are sure I would like you to demonstrate it, because I do not think you are correct. A dot product cannot have the interference terms.

Comment: $\psi^*(x)\psi(x)$ is not a dot product, it needs to be integrated to be one, and the spectrum has nothing to do with it. The continuity of the spectrum has to do with the normalizability of the wave function; interference terms will appear in the linear sum whether you can normalize it or not.

Comment: I think the spectrum does have something to do with it. When the spectrum is discrete we take the dot (inner) product of the state vector, we do not integrate.

Comment: what is that dot product?

Comment: I show it in my third equation for a general state vector for an observable with a discrete spectrum. There are no interference terms.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Please try to explain more clearly. But with a laser, beam splitters and quarter- and half-wave plates, you can observe interference in the polarization of photons, which are definitely observables with a discrete spectrum.

Comment: You need to elaborate on your claim, "the corresponding probability distribution is given by $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle$". The probability distribution of what? $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle$ isn't even a distribution, it's literally just the number $1$.

Comment: Hyportnex's comment is correct, and I think you just have a misconception about what inner products and probabilities mean.

Comment: Maybe OP has an orthonormal eigenbasis in mind? But then the mixed term disappears in both the discrete and the continuous case so there is no difference again.

Comment: I think my problem is not understanding the difference between $\langle\psi|\psi\rangle$ and $|\psi(x)|^2$

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment. Let me rephrase it. I think my problem is not understanding the difference between $\langle\psi|\psi\rangle$ and $|\psi|^2$

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with interference here, there is a problem that you are misinterpreting the symbols you are using:

1. There is no difference between the discrete and the continuous case, there is *always* a "dot product", more formally a *Hermitian inner product*, on our Hilbert space. That in the case of finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces $\mathbb{C}^n$ it looks like the ordinary dot product of vectors and in the case of the infinite-dimensional space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ of wavefunctions it looks like an integral is immaterial, it is an inner product in all cases. The inner product between two wavefunctions $\psi(x),\phi(x)$ is $\langle \phi\vert\psi\rangle = \int \phi^\ast(x)\psi(x)\mathrm{d}^n x$. In particular this means that if your two wavefunctions $\psi_1,\psi_2$ are orthogonal eigenfunctions of something, then the "interference" term vanishes in the continuous just as in the discrete case.
2. Given *any* quantum state $\lvert \psi\rangle$, $\langle \psi\vert\psi\rangle$ is *not* a "probability distribution". It is a physically meaningless normalization factor that is usually fixed to be 1. So is $\int \psi^\ast (x) \psi(x)$, when the integral is over all of space.
3. The object $\rho(x) = \psi^\ast(x)\psi(x) = \lvert \psi(x)\rvert^2$ is *not* the analogue of $\langle \psi \vert \psi\rangle$, but the analogue of $\langle \psi\vert x\rangle\langle x \vert \psi\rangle$, where $\lvert x\rangle$ is an eigenstate of the position operator (whose existence is rigorously a delicate question, but which we should just assume for now). By the Born rule, this is a probability (density) to detect the state $\lvert \psi\rangle$ as having position value $x$. So integrating the density $\rho(x)$ over a certain interval $[a,b]$ is also (sloppily)
   $$\int_a^b \rho(x)\mathrm{d}x = \langle \psi \vert \left(\int_a^b \lvert x\rangle\langle x\rvert\right)\vert \psi\rangle,$$
   and yields the probability to detect the object in the region $[a,b]$. Note that for $a,b\to -\infty,\infty$, this becomes just $\langle \psi\vert\psi\rangle$ and so is just 1 - as the integral of a probability density over all possible events should be.

Comment: So you are saying that the interference terms drop out for the continuous case just as it is missing in the discrete case. So how do we get a probability distribution that contains the interference terms?

Comment: Is this equality incorrect? If so, ,what am I missing...$$\langle\psi|\psi\rangle=|\psi|^2$$

Comment: @hooch As I wrote, you have $\langle \psi \vert \psi\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \lvert \psi(x)\vert^2$ and you get interference terms by, well, actually computing a probability distribution instead of the normalization factor. Alas, "interference term" is a bit of a vague notion, so I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: I think the state vector $|\psi\rangle$ represents a probability amplitude distribution in some n-dimensional space of n possible outcomes.  In this n-dimensional space how do I represent the probability distribution for the n-possible outcomes? Is it also a n-dimensional vector?

Comment: Adding to my previous comment...Assuming the probability distribution is also a vector, is it a vector in which the components are the squares of the components of the probability amplitude vector?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your [rephrased question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/326968/8), suppose you have some observable $\hat A$ with a discrete spectrum $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$, with corresponding eigenstates $\{|n⟩:n=1,2,3,\ldots\}$ forming an orthonormal basis. Then any state $|\psi⟩$ can be represented in the form
$$
|\psi⟩ = \sum_n c_n |n⟩, \quad\text{where }c_n = ⟨n|\psi⟩.
$$
Here the $c_n = ⟨n|\psi⟩$ are the probability amplitudes for each of the measurements, and they are analogous to the wavefunction $\psi(x)=⟨x|\psi⟩$ (i.e. the probability density amplitude) of the continuous case.

The analogue of the probability density $|\psi(x)|^2=⟨\psi|x⟩⟨x|\psi⟩$ of the continuous case in discrete QM is then simply
$$
|c_n|^2 = ⟨\psi|n⟩⟨n|\psi⟩,
$$
and it is known as the occupation probability of the state $|\psi⟩$ for that eigenstate.

---

If you have a superposition state, 
$$
|\psi⟩=|\psi_1⟩+|\psi_2⟩, \text{ where }|\psi_1⟩ = \sum_n c_n^{(1)} |n⟩ \text{ and } |\psi_2⟩ = \sum_n c_n^{(2)} |n⟩,
$$
so that
$$
|\psi⟩ = \sum_n c_n |n⟩ =  \sum_n \left(c_n^{(1)} + c_n^{(1)} \right) |n⟩
$$
and therefore $c_n |n⟩ =  c_n^{(1)} + c_n^{(1)}$, then the corresponding measurement probability of outcome $a_n$ is given by
$$
|c_n|^2 
= \left|c_n^{(1)}+c_n^{(2)}\right|^2
= \left|c_n^{(1)}\right|^2+\left|c_n^{(2)}\right|^2+ 2\operatorname{Re}\left({c_n^{(1)}}^*c_n^{(2)}\right),
$$
where the last term represents interference, *exactly* as in the continuous case.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for in the discrete case. Now back to my question regarding interference. When $|\psi\rangle$ is considered to be in a superposition of its eigenstates, how do we get interference terms in the probability distribution?

Comment: @hooch For future reference, this kind of switching back and forth between different questions is *strongly* discouraged.

Comment: What is your reasoning for your final equation?

Comment: @Emilo don't worry about my switching back and forth, you and your friends will take away all my points so I cant post another question, just like you did before.

Comment: @hooch See edit. I won't do any more back and forth on this answer, though.

Comment: Ok, I see your reasoning now. That is actually the best analysis I have seen on this.

Comment: I just want to write out one of your statements ... $|c_n|^2=c_n^*c_n=\langle\psi|n\rangle\langle n|\psi\rangle$ and noting that $c_n = \langle n|\psi\rangle$ and $c_n^*=\langle\psi|n\rangle = \langle n|\psi\rangle^*$